# How to create SDK with framework that using cocoa-pods

Tags: frameworks, cocoapods, cocoapods-1.2

I have a framework that using with some cocoa pods.
now I'm trying to create SDK from the framework, but don't show all the classes, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the public keyword is in front of your class declaration - they changed the scope default from public by default to private.